# I need to transfer an already built maven project to a new machine

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, spring-tool-suite

I cannot build the project again on the new machine as I do not have access to the Maven repository, nor do I have the access to the git repository. How would I accomplish this? I would assume that I would only need to copy the project directory along with the `c:\users\...\.m2\repository` over to the new machine, but I'm sure there is more to it than just these two steps.

Asked another way, the question is: How do I share/host/daisy-chain a private Git repository so that I can easily access it when I'm not on the network?

I copied over my eclipse directory, my .m2 directory, as well as my project directory. I have tons of "Cannot be resolved to a type" errors. Clearly, something is missing here.

Comment: these are mostly what you need to do, given that I assume you have already properly setup your `settings.xml`.  Give it a try first and ask here if you encountered any specific problem

Comment: what do you mean by saying "cannot build the object again"? what's the error information?

Comment: @cainiaofei - Building the project requires access to an internal repository which I do not have access to. i.e. Maven tries to fetch dependencies from an intranet ip address.

Comment: What's in `.m2/repository` is portable, you can zip it and copy it on some USB-drive for example that should be all you need

Comment: @RC. If the original `.m2/repository` resided under `C:\Users\Ali` and the destination will be under `C:\Users\Shazia` wouldn't I need to make any changes to the pom file, or any other settings?

Comment: @AdrianShum I copied the `.m2` repository, my eclipse folder and my project folder. Everything shows up as expected except for many, many "Cannot be resolved to a Type" errors. Clearly, a simple copying over of files does not work. Can you please elaborate on what changes need to be made to this `settings.xml`? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reconfigure `repository` tag in your `pom.xml` like this

```
<repositories>
    <!-- make this repository at the first item in the list -->

    <repository>
        <id>local</id>
        <url>file://[your custom .m2 path]</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <!-- other repositories here -->
    </repository>

</repositories>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was getting at :) There is more to it than simply copying over files.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the `USER/.m2/` folder from the machine which you built the project on to the new machine then maven will be able to find the dependencies without going to an external repository.

Comment: I copied over my eclipse folder, along with my project folder, and also my .m2 repository in an effort to replicate the same environment on another machine. I now have tons of "cannot be resolved to a type" errors. Clearly, something is missing.